# Interpretation of cv.tree plot

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, cart

I am conducting research using regression trees and I was hoping someone here could help me understand the following cv.tree plot.

[image]

I understand that the x-axis (bottom) represents the size of the tree and the y axis represents the cross-validation error (SSR + alpha*size). I also understand that the alpha parameter is selected through 10 fold cross-validation.

What I do not understand is why this plot displays multiple values for alpha on the top x-axis. Shouldn’t we only have one level of alpha, and compare the cross-validation error across models using this single value for alpha? Wouldn’t introducing multiple values of alpha for different sized models defeat the purpose of this approach, as the complexity penalty (alpha*size) then differs on tree size?

For context, I am following the intuition from the example on page 328 of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/) using my own dataset.

Code:

```
library(tree)

#set seed
set.seed(2021)
#Create test/training set - sample(x, size)
train = sample(1:nrow(treedf), nrow(treedf)*0.75)

#create tree on training set 
tree.FMC=tree(wcdciga40 ~ .,treedf, subset=train, control = tree.control(5952,mindev=.003))
summary(tree.FMC)

#check cross validation to see if pruning will improve performance 
plot(cv.tree(tree.FMC, K=10))
```

And for bonus points, how is the cross-validation error equal from tree sizes 3 to 11? Wouldn't this suggest that the decrease in SSR is exactly offset by an increase in the cost complexity parameter for each increase in tree size above 3?

Thank you!

Ben.